# How do i keep my current page menu highlighted on pagination?

Tags: menus, css, javascript

I have a navigation menu in a page that highlights the current menu you’re on based on the URL by adding a class.

My problem is that my page is paginated, so sometimes the user will end up at:

`http://example.com:4001/wordpress/calientes/page/2/` ,
/page/3/ , /page/4/ and so on...

what’s the best way to keep my menu highlighted while the user is browsing the pages?

This is my menu:

```
<div class="innerhead">

<ul>

<code><li> <a href="http://example.com:4001/wordpress/calientes/">Calientes </a> </li>
<li><a href="http://example.com:4001/wordpress/tendencias/">Tendencias</a></li>
</code>
</ul>

</div>
```

This is the Script that use to highlight the current page menu:

```
<script>
$(function(){
    // this will get the full URL at the address bar
    var url = window.location.href; 

    // passes on every "a" tag 
    $(".innerhead a").each(function() {
            // checks if its the same on the address bar
        if(url == (this.href)) { 
            $(this).closest("li").addClass("active");
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Close-voted as **off-topic**. As-written, this is a **CSS/JS** question, *not* a **WordPress** question. Per the WPSE FAQ, questions not specific to WordPress are out of scope, *even if they happen in the context of WordPress**.

Comment: I don't understand why you're adding the class *after* the menu is clicked... Anyway, if you want help here, you should show the PHP you're using to build the menu; and how this pagination is happening.